# How to pass a function call as an argument to an Excel macro via Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, office-interop

I'm trying to call an Excel macro that, as its first parameter, calls a function.

Let's say I have this subroutine in Excel

```
Sub ValidateSheet(version As Integer, displayNoErrorsBox As Boolean)
```

which I can call inside Excel like this:

```
Call Validation.ValidateSheet(Data.GetVersion, False)
```

`Data.GetVersion` returns an integer, of course.

How do I do this via C# Excel interop?

Every parameter passed is an object. All tutorials and posts I can find pass strings. Is it possible to pass the function call as a string?

This doesn't work:

```
m_Application.Run("Validation.ValidateSheet", "Data.GetVersion", "False");
```

Comment: The reason "all tutorials and posts I can find on this subject simply pass strings" is because that is what  `Validation.ValidateSheet(Data.GetVersion, False)` does.  Parameters are evaluated before they are passed to the called procedure.  You'll need to get a `Data` object in your C# code, call `.GetVersion` on it, and pass that as the first parameter.

Comment: Right. Sounds logical and straightforward, expect that I'm an newbie to all things Interop. Can you be a bit more specific on the Data object? Looking through the namespace, it doesn't jump out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: No clue. There isn't an Excel class or interface named `Data`, and nothing with a `GetVersion` member (at least as of Excel 2013).  You'll need to look at the VBA code to find out.  FWIW, you can't pass `Validation` to `Application.Run` either - it's an object.

Comment: Ok, you meant the "Data" that I'm specifying! That's the name of a module inside the .xslm, which contains a "GetVersion" subroutine which returns an int (both are user-defined). I'm looking to pass that call as an object.

Comment: Then make that call (via `m_Application.Run`) and pass the result in the next call to `m_Application.Run`.

Comment: Yep, and that was it (i missed that you can actually get the return type from the macro!). If you add this an the official answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used the suggestion from the comments and called the first macro explicitly.

So, instead of trying this:

```
m_Application.Run("Validation.ValidateSheet", "Data.GetVersion", false);
```

I'm doing this:

```
string version = m_Application.Run("Data.GetVersion");
m_Application.Run("Validation.ValidateSheet", version, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //~~> Define your Excel Objects
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

            //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\Users\\Siddharth Rout\\Desktop\\book1.xlsm");

            //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
            xlApp.Run("ShowMsg", "Hello from C# Client", "Demo to run Excel macros from C#");

            //~~> Clean-up: Close the workbook
            xlWorkBook.Close(false);

            //~~> Quit the Excel Application
            xlApp.Quit();

            //~~> Clean Up
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        }

        //~~> Release the objects
        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/2e33b8e5-c9fd-42a1-8d67-3d61d2cedc1c/how-to-call-excel-macros-programmatically-in-c?forum=exceldev

Comment: No offense, but did you actually read the question and comment thread? Your copy/paste answer doesn't answer the question at all, it just passes some string parameters along.